# how do i open and run(execute) a file at java?

Tags: file, csv, java

i am trying to develop a j2se program that copy a .csv for special task.
Now i want to run(execute) that copied .csv file.

if copied paht is **"C:\program files\reports\test.csv"** or 
**C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\test.csv"** it dose not work for this code:

***run.exec("cmd start /c C:/Documents and setting\user\My Documents\test.csv");***

and for this code:

if path gets form a JTextField or JFileChooser, how is works?

note taht in during of running of this program users may set their special path.

thank u for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class introduced in Java 6 if possible:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filename));
```

Less problems with separating commands, and it's platform-independant.

Comment: +1. Forgot about that one. Anyway, retaining my answer for pre Java-6

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes around the path, and either use forward slashes, or use double backward slashes:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd start /c \"C:/Documents and setting/user/My Documents/test.csv\"");
```

Update: Use Michael's solution for Java 6.

Comment: I think it should be `...My Documents/test.csv...` instead of `...My Documents\test.csv...`

Comment: @danoo - it could also be File.separator :)

Comment: Yes, that's a different topic. Using forward slashes is fine, because the Sun JVM is normalizing the path, although File.separator is preferable.

Comment: Isn't the argument being passed as is to `cmd.exe`? How can the JVM know that it's a path? I am pretty sure that it is `cmd.exe` who is doing the magic (works fine if started in the command line window {XP}).

Comment: @mahdi - no. You have to add quotes.

Comment: @Bozho - if path get from an JTextField and use form getText() it works? for example Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd start /c"+jTextField.getText());

Comment: well try it. it should work if all quotes and slashes are fine.

Comment: @Bozho - thank you for your solution, although your solution is correct, but Michael Borgwardt's sloution is better.

Comment: @mahdi - that's what I said, too :)